# AWS dll for reference in c# project

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I've installed the [AWS .NET SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/) through the MSI installer. I would like to use this code:

```
static IAmazonS3 client;
client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
{
  BucketName = bucketName,
  Key = keyName,
  FilePath = filePath
};
PutObjectResponse response2 = client.PutObject(request);
```

If I manually browse to a dll to add a reference to the project I can see the following libraries - which do I use so that the above is possible? The only functionality I need is to be able to put objects to S3.

[image]

---

note

I don't want to create an AWS project using one of the AWS templates - I just need to add the above functionality into an existing project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation, [Getting Started with the AWS SDK for .NET — Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-setup.html):

> You can also base your application on one of the standard Visual Studio project templates. Just add a reference to the AWS .NET library (AWSSDK.dll), which is located in the `past-releases` folder of the the SDK installation directory.

So you just need to reference AWSSDK.dll from the `past-releases` directory.

According to your screenshot, you're looking in the wrong place, namely in one of the Toolkit for Visual Studio directories.

For earlier versions of the SDK (version 1 and 2), you find the assemblies in `C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\past-releases\Version-1\` and `..\Version-2` respectively. Version 3 is installed (by default) in `C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin`.

So: for V1 and V2, you just need to reference the appropriate `AWSSDK.dll`. For V3 you need to reference `AWSSDK.Core.dll` and the assemblies for the services you want to use, in your case `AWSSDK.S3.dll`.

That being said, [using the NuGet package manager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-install-assemblies.html) is way easier to do this.